# Buttons on top of html/javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, cytoscape.js

I have a `<div>` element in which I load `cytoscape.js` which is just a tool to draw graphs.

In the top corner of this `<div>` element, I want some buttons (`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">`, etc.).

I want something like [this example](http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/f70c9e45c43f40f7dfe1/). In the example, the `cytoscape` elements are on top of the `<h1>` element because the `<div>` element has `position: absolute; height: 100%; z-index: 999; ...`. I want it reversed, so the other elements are on top of the `cytoscape` canvas.

I also want a top navbar.

I guess I should use something like

```
<div id="navbar" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 999; width: 100%; height: 50px;>
</div>
<div id="main" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 100; width: 100%; height: 100%;>
    <button type="button">Some text</button>
</div>
```

If I use this approach, the page becomes more than 100% in height (the vertical scrollbar becomes visible).. And if I click one of the buttons, it means that I also click in the "main" `<div>` element, which causes the javascript to create a node.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting question/problem details as comments.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but isn't this just a CSS issue? Make a container div with `position:relative`. Then first add a cytoscape child div. Then add your buttons as children. All the children are positioned with `position:absolute`. In the Javascript handler for the buttons you can include `event.stopPropagation` to keep the button click events from bubbling to your other elements.